# ansible - ensure content of file is the same across servers

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible 2.9.12

**Question:** How do I configure Ansible to ensure the contents of a file is equal amongst at least 3 hosts, when the file is present at at least one host?

Imagine there are 3 hosts.

Host 1 does not has `/file.txt`.

Host 2 has `/file.txt` with contents `hello`.

Host 3 has `/file.txt` with contents `hello`.

Before the play is run, I am unaware whether the file is present or not. So the file could exist on host1, or host2 or host3. But the file exists on at least one of the hosts.

How would I ensure each time Ansible runs, the files across the hosts are equal. So in the end, Host 1 has the same file with the same contents as Host 2 or Host 3.

I'd like this to be dynamically set, instead of specifying the host names or group names, e.g. `when: inventory_hostname == host1`.

I am not expecting a check to see whether the contents of host 2 and 3 are equal

I do however, want this to be setup in an idempotent fashion.

Comment: Is it something different to what the [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) module can do?

Comment: I only want to use the module when at a hosts, the file is not present. Before the play is run, I am unaware whether the file is present or not.

Comment: so the file if exists on any hosts lets say 3 then you need to copy the file from 3 to host 2 and host 1, right ? If yes, you can use `rsync` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html and `delegate_to`

Comment: but beforehand I don't know on which machine the file exists. It could exist on either 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play below does the job, I think

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Get status.
      stat:
        path: /file.txt
      register: status
    - block:
        - name: Create dictionary status.
          set_fact:
            status: "{{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}"
          vars:
            keys: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
            values: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['status','stat','exists'])|
                        list }}"
        - name: Fail. No file exists.
          fail:
            msg: No file exists
          when: status.values()|list is not any
        - name: Set reference to first host with file present.
          set_fact:
            reference: "{{ status|dict2items|
                           selectattr('value')|
                           map(attribute='key')|
                           first }}"
        - name: Fetch file.
          fetch:
            src: /file.txt
            dest: /tmp
          delegate_to: "{{ reference }}"
      run_once: true
    - name: Copy file if not exist
      copy:
        src: "/tmp/{{ reference }}/file.txt"
        dest: /file.txt
      when: not status[inventory_hostname]
```

But, this doesn't check the existing files are in sync. It would be safer to sync all hosts, I think

```yaml
    - name: Synchronize file
      synchronize:
        src: "/tmp/{{ reference }}/file.txt"
        dest: /file.txt
      when: not status[inventory_hostname]
```

---

> Q: *"FATAL. could not find or access '/tmp/test-multi-01/file.txt on the Ansible controller. However, folder /tmp/test-multi-03 is present with the file.txt in it."*

A: There is a problem with the [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) module when the task is delegated to another host. When the `TASK [Fetch file.]` is delegated to `test-multi-01` which is localhost in this case `changed: [test-multi-03 -> 127.0.0.1]` the file will be fetched from `test-multi-01` but will be stored in `/tmp/test-multi-03/file.txt`. The conclusion is, the `fetch` module ignores `delegate_to` when it comes to creating host-specific directories ([not reported yet](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues)).

As a workaround, it's possible to set `flat: true` and store the files in a specific directory. For example, add the variable `sync_files_dir` with the directory, set fetch `flat: true`, and use the directory to both fetch and copy the file

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    sync_files_dir: /tmp/sync_files
  tasks:
    - name: Get status.
      stat:
        path: /file.txt
      register: status
    - block:
        - name: Create dir for files to be fetched and synced
          file:
            state: directory
            path: "{{ sync_files_dir }}"
          delegate_to: localhost
        - name: Create dictionary status.
          set_fact:
            status: "{{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}"
          vars:
            keys: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
            values: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['status','stat','exists'])|
                        list }}"
        - debug:
            var: status
        - name: Fail. No file exists.
          fail:
            msg: No file exists
          when: status.values()|list is not any
        - name: Set reference to first host with file present.
          set_fact:
            reference: "{{ status|dict2items|
                           selectattr('value')|
                           map(attribute='key')|
                           first }}"
        - name: Fetch file.
          fetch:
            src: /file.txt
            dest: "{{ sync_files_dir }}/"
            flat: true
          delegate_to: "{{ reference }}"
      run_once: true
    - name: Copy file if not exist
      copy:
        src: "{{ sync_files_dir }}/file.txt"
        dest: /file.txt
      when: not status[inventory_hostname]
```

Comment: Got a FATAL. `could not find or access '/tmp/test-multi-01/file.txt` on the ansible controller. However, folder /tmp/test-multi-03 is present with the file.txt in it.

Comment: Because run_once. It selects the first node in the run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220534/discussion-between-kevin-c-and-vladimir-botka).

Comment: Hhm, it seems that when there is another (4th) host in the play, which skips all these tasks, the task ` Create dictionary status.` doesn't work properly. Perhaps you know how to fix this @Vladimir?

Comment: This should not happen. No host can skip the task `Get status`, i.e. all hosts shall be included in the status. Open a new question with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Never mind, it was a pebkac issue. It seems that variable 'status' is required, even on the skipped host.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it by fetching the file from hosts where the file exists. The file(s) will be available on the control machine. However if the file which will be the source, exists on more than 1 node, then there will be *no single source of truth*.

Consider an inventory:

```ini
[my_hosts]
host1
host2
host3
```

Then the below play can fetch the file, then use that file to copy to all nodes.

```yaml
# Fetch the file from remote host if it exists
- hosts: my_hosts

  tasks:
  - stat:
      path: /file.txt
    register: my_file
  - fetch:
      src: /file.txt
      dest: /tmp/
    when: my_file.stat.exists
  - find:
      paths:
      - /tmp
      patterns: file.txt
      recurse: yes
    register: local_file
    delegate_to: localhost
  - copy:
      src: "{{ local_file.files[0].path }}"
      dest: /tmp
```

If multiple hosts had this file then it would be in `/tmp/{{ ansible_host }}`. Then as we won't have a single source of truth, our best estimate can be to use the first file and apply on all hosts.

Comment: This really feels like a workaround. E.g. this isn't possible to put in an Ansible role. And you're still using groups['my_hosts'], which is undesired.

Comment: Ok, well the same logic can be applied, by switching the `delegate_to` to localhost. I will update the answer.

Comment: Sweet. Would it work if there were multiple files? E.g. /file1.txt and /file2.txt

Comment: You mean different filenames but specific content like "hello" as in original question? We could use `contents: hello` in `find` task for that.

Answer (score -1):

Well i believe the get_url module is pretty versatile - allows for local file paths or paths from a web server. Try it and let me know.

```
 - name: Download files in all host
   hosts: all 
   tasks:
    - name: Download file from a file path
      get_url:
        url: file:///tmp/file.txt
        dest: /tmp/
```

Edited ans:
(From documentation: For the synchronize module, the “local host” is the host the synchronize task originates on, and the “destination host” is the host synchronize is connecting to)

```
  - name: Check that the file exists
    stat:
      path: /etc/file.txt
    register: stat_result

  - name: copy the file to other hosts by delegating the task to the source host
    synchronize:
      src: path/host
      dest: path/host
    delegate_to: my_source_host
    when: stat_result.stat.exists
```

Comment: Obviously, this doesn't work. Since the file is not present at host1. See output: https://pastebin.com/9X68h4t7

Comment: my bad. Skipped through a few lines while reading. Is the path for your text file similar across the 3 hosts? How about using stat module to get the file status and use file.stat with a logic statement to proceed with copying to the other hosts.

Comment: The path is indeed equal. However, what is the logical statement?

Comment: I added in the general idea for the logical statement that i had in mind.

Comment: Ye, but how... that's the question.

Comment: a series of synchronize delegate_to and when mods should do the trick. the when module checks if the file exists in the specified host and executes the sync command by delegating it to the specified host that has the file in the path ^ refer above

Comment: I think it's trickier than you think. Please, provide an updated answer.