# ansible - set fact for all hosts in play, when only one host has a met condition

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible v2.9.12

**Question:** How do I set a variable for all hosts in the play, when at least one host has a certain condition which is met.

Example:

```
- hosts:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
    - host4
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /tmp/file
      register: something

    - set_fact
        something: true
      when: something <at least one of the hosts has /tmp/file>
```

Now, only host4 has `/tmp/file` present in it's filesystem. How would I set the fact for all hosts in this case?

Comment: You'll for sure want to start by adding `register:` to that `stat:` otherwise you can't tell anything about its outcome; please also [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63619004/edit) and say what you have tried and what error it is producing

Comment: It's actually a duplicate of [what you used today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598312/ansible-ensure-content-of-file-is-the-same-across-servers). Instead of **fail** `when: ... is not any` **set_fact** `when: ... is any`.

Comment: @mdaniel not everything requires own work, right? I didn't see the trees anymore through the woods. Anyway, vladimir you've pointed me in the right direction, and I've got it working.

Answer (score 3):

With help from Vladimir Botka:

```
---
- hosts:
    - test-multi-03
    - test-multi-02
    - test-multi-01
  tasks:
    - name: stat file
      stat:
        path: /tmp/file
      register: status

    - block:

        - name: create dictionary
          set_fact:
            status: "{{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}"
          vars:
            keys: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
            values: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['status','stat','exists'])
                        | list }}"

        - name: set fact when file is present on at least one host, for all hosts
          set_fact:
            something: yeah
          when: status.values() | list is any

      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ something }}"
      when: something is defined
```