# Select host to execute task based on multiple conditions

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible v2.9.12

Imagine 4 hosts in a play, with the following vars:

```
# host1
my_var:
  one: true
  two: master

# host2
my_var:
  one: false
  two: master

# host3
my_var:
  one: false
  two: master

# host4
my_var:
  one: false
  two: arbiter
```

I want to execute a task on a single host, which is has `my_var.two == 'master'` and has `my_var.one` set to `false`. In this case it would relate to either host2 or host3.

Now, this won't work:

```
- shell: echo
  when: 
    - my_var.two == 'master'
    - not my_var.one
   run_once: true
```

Because Ansible executes the task only on the first host in the group, which most likely relates to host1, which is undesired. I'm also fiddling around in [the answer described in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619004/ansible-set-fact-for-all-hosts-in-play-when-only-one-host-has-a-met-condition?noredirect=1#comment112500549_63619004), which is somewhat related, but without avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing stops you, in a playbook, to have multiple plays:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ my_var }}"

- hosts: host2
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ my_var }}"
      # ^--- Off course, now the when become superfluous, 
      #      since we target a host that we know have those conditions

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Keep on going with all hosts"
```

Would give the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": {
        "one": true,
        "two": "master"
    }
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": {
        "one": false,
        "two": "master"
    }
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": {
        "one": false,
        "two": "master"
    }
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": {
        "one": false,
        "two": "arbiter"
    }
}

PLAY [host2] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": {
        "one": false,
        "two": "master"
    }
}

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "Keep on going with all hosts"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Keep on going with all hosts"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "Keep on going with all hosts"
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "Keep on going with all hosts"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Alternatively, for a more dynamic solution, you could select the correct host, looping through your hosts variables via the magic variable [`hostvars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) and, then, delegate the task to this host with [`delegate_to`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        host_master_not_one: "{{ item }}"
      when:
        - host_master_not_one is not defined
        - not hostvars[item].my_var.one
        - "'master' == hostvars[item].my_var.two"
      run_once: true
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}" 
    
    - debug: 
        msg: "Running only once, on host {{ host_master_not_one }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ host_master_not_one }}"
      run_once: true
```

It gives the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host1] => (item=host1) 
ok: [host1] => (item=host2)
skipping: [host1] => (item=host3) 
skipping: [host1] => (item=host4) 

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> host2] => {
    "msg": "Running only once, on host host2"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The important part of this recap would be the `[host1 -> host2]` that indicates that the task was delegated and so run on `host2`.

---

Or even, on the same train of thoughts, skip hosts that does not match the one having those said conditions:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        host_master_not_one: "{{ item }}"
      when:
        - host_master_not_one is not defined
        - not hostvars[item].my_var.one
        - "'master' == hostvars[item].my_var.two"
      run_once: true
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}" 
    
    - debug: 
        msg: "Running only once, on host {{ host_master_not_one }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == host_master_not_one
```

Gives the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host1] => (item=host1) 
ok: [host1] => (item=host2)
skipping: [host1] => (item=host3) 
skipping: [host1] => (item=host4) 

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host1]
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Running only once, on host host2"
}
skipping: [host3]
skipping: [host4]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I really love this answer. Simple, clean and it works! Thanks

Comment: perhaps change hostvars to ansible_play_hosts, to limit it only to the current play, instead of all hostvars available.